# jQuery.inArray always returns -1

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a DataTables multiple row selection going, in which they use the code:

```
if ( $.inArray(1, 1) !== -1 ) {
   $(row).addClass('selected');
}
```

To check if certain row have already been selected. However, every equation which I put in the `$.inArray` return -1. I have tried some in the console of my browser such as `$.inArray(1,3)`, `$.inArray([1],[3])`, `$.inArray(["1"],["3"])`, `$.inArray(1,1)`, `$.inArray([1],[1])` but all return -1! According to the documentation of jQuery this should be possible...

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: $.inArray(1, [1])==0 sure https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: You need an `Array` to check against: `$.inArray(1, [1])`

Comment: Thanks! That is finally working!

Comment: that method takes 2 (required) params - first is a value to find second is an array. None of your combinations pass approriate parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply using it wrong =)

The **first argument** is the `value` you want to find and the **second argument** is the actual `Array` to search the value in.

So you should have something like:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];

... $.inArray(1, array) ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I indeed missed that part